# How to create SplitView Controller similar to setting in ipad?

Tags: objective-c, uisplitviewcontroller

I want to create spiltview controller similar to setting on the ipad.That means even in portrait mode the lefthand side panel should be visible as it appears in landscape mode.Hope I am able to explain what I want.Please can anyone know how I can achieve this?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ray Wenderlich has a nice tutorial on this subject that walks you through the steps:

- [iPad for iPhone developers 101: UISplitView Tutorial](http://www.raywenderlich.com/1040/ipad-for-iphone-developers-101-uisplitview-tutorial)

Comment: Thanks John, Really your response helped me alot.

Comment: Tutorial is simple. this is not about setting mode.